# JBoss JDBC Dynamic Connector using restlet

Tags: jdbc, apache-camel, esb, jbossfuse, connector

I need to create dynamic JDBC Connector, i.e., it has to dynamically pick driver for different SQL.

The dataSource as bean in camelContext.xml works fine.

I am trying to create REST way so the credentials and other info to connect to DB will be taken as JSON and the operation must be carried,

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the processor class, getDataSource method is called with few mandatory parameters : host, port, username, rdbmsType and password in model object.

```
DataSource ds = DBCPDataSourceFactory.getDataSource(model);
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
connection = ds.getConnection();
statement = connection.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(model.getQuery());
```

Datasource class :

```
public class DBCPDataSourceFactory {
public static DataSource getDataSource(DBModel model) {
    String url = null;
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    if (model.getRdbms().toLowerCase().equals(DBConstants.POSTGRESQL)) {
        ds.setDriverClassName(DBConstants.POSTGRESQL_DRIVER);
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + model.getHost() + "/" + model.getDatabase();
        ds.setUrl(url); 
    } else if (model.getRdbms().toLowerCase().equals(DBConstants.ORACLE)) {
        ds.setDriverClassName(DBConstants.ORACLE_DRIVER);
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+model.getHost()+":"+model.getPort()+":"+model.getDatabase();
        ds.setUrl(url);
    } else if (model.getRdbms().toLowerCase().equals(DBConstants.SQL_SERVER)) {
        ds.setDriverClassName(DBConstants.SQL_SERVER_DRIVER);           
        url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+model.getHost()+":"+model.getPort()+";databaseName="+model.getDatabase();
        ds.setUrl(url);
    }
    ds.setUsername(model.getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(model.getPassword());
    return ds;
}}
```